# AngularJS: ngRouter cannot work

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

Because the UI-Route cannot work with directive (it has the unbreakable isolated scope) and cannot fit [my scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46845845/angularjs-nest-directive-in-ng-repeat-for-using-smart-table-with-dynamic-table), I'm testing to remove the UI-Route and go for ngRoute. I spent a day on the ngRoute and it still did not work. I think there must be some subtle mistake in my code but I just cannot figure it out. The simplified test code is as bellow:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="Hello" ng-strict-di>

<head>
  <title>Hello</title>
  <script script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.6/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    'use strict';
    angular.module('Hello', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.when('/hello', {
        templateUrl: 'hello.html',
        controller: 'Ctrl1'
      }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: "/"
      });
    }])
    .controller('Ctrl1', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
      $scope.content = 'Hello World!';
    }]);
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <h1>Demo</h1>
    <a href="#/hello">click me</a>
  </div>
  <ng-view></ng-view>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="hello.html">
    <p>{{content}}</p>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Really appreciate if you may help me out.

Comment: are there any error?

Comment: did you try with `localhost`?

Comment: @Avnesh I'm trying above with in the localhost. but in my real scenario I fetched the data to be shown from the server.

Comment: @Sajeetharan There is no error at the console. If I put something like `console.log('test')` in the beginning of controller it does not show -- the route failed and the controller is not called.

Comment: @Oops Try using  <a href="#!/hello">click me</a>for your anchor tags since you are using angular 1.6

Comment: Thank you @Vivz this solution worked!

Comment: Glad to be of help. I have provided an answer below, please accept it if you find it helpful :) @Oops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use  `<a href="#!/hello">click me</a>` since you are using angular 1.6.x. You have to append an exclamation mark ! to your href.

**For more reference:** [Angular All slashes in URL changed to %2F](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41272314/angular-all-slashes-in-url-changed-to-2f)

Comment: Thank you this finally saved me at the end of the day!